# When is Dlib's svm_c_linear_trainer better than svm_c_linear_dcd_trainer?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, training-data, dlib

I have a machine learning problem with high-dimensional labelled inputs and a relatively small sample size. Using the very cool [visual guide](http://dlib.net/ml_guide.svg) brought me to the `svm_c_linear_trainer` method. But what I understand from the documentation is that the similar `svm_c_linear_dcd_trainer` has the option to 'warm-start', which sounds like a better thing to do than 'cold-start', e.g., inside a cross-validation loop. However, `svm_c_linear_dcd_trainer` is the selected method for a different type of problem, the main difference being application to unlabelled data.

Would there be a problem in using `svm_c_linear_dcd_trainer` on labelled data, or is there another good reason why `svm_c_linear_trainer` is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/cddual.pdf) about the Dual-Descent SVM and also the [documentation](http://dlib.net/ml.html#svm_c_linear_dcd_trainer) on DLib's website show, that `svm_c_linear_dcd_trainer` **can be used as a drop-in replacement** of the standard linear SVM.

It is supposed to have superior performance (quote from mentioned article):

> Experiments show that our
>   method is faster than state of the art implementations.

... because the algorithm supposedly makes better use of optimization while giving the same results the standard SVM algorithms would give.

*Page 6 & 7 in the article, in which it is compared to other algorithms on several different datasets might be especially interesting to you.*